# sudoers: can´t run 2 command lists where the second has a glob * and denies the first

Tags: linux, shell, arguments, sudo, sudoers

so, what I want is:

- to be able to run `/sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --view` as
  another user without asking password.
- to be able to run    `/sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --cancel`
  (or `--delete`, or    `--pause`, etc) as another user but asking for
  password.

Preferably, I didn´t want to create a Cmnd_Alias with all possible arguents. So, I tried the three aliases and the User Specification below:

```
Host_Alias      PRINTSRVS = printsrv, printsrvbkp
Cmnd_Alias      APP1PMV = /sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --view
Cmnd_Alias      APP1PMD = /sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 *, !APP1PMV

%app1adms, %helpdesk PRINTSRVS = (printop2:printop2) NOPASSWD: APP1PMV, \
                                 (printop2:printop2) PASSWD: APP1PMD
```

When I run `sudo -u printop2 /sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --cancel` it works:

```
[sudo] password for app1adm1:
Managing queue...
```

But when I run `sudo -u printop2 /sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --view` it doesn't:

```
Sorry, user app1adm1 is not allowed to execute '/sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --view' as printop2 on printsrv.
```

Apparently my second command `(printop2:printop2) PASSWD: APP1PMD` overrode my first command `(printop2:printop2) NOPASSWD: APP1PMV` and denied the `--view` argument altogether.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww there are lots of questions about sudo in Stack Overflow. Why mine specifically is off-topic?

Comment: Your question is not being targeted. Most of sudo questions are likely off-topic. I think the problem is, we don't have unlimited votes to close all off-topic stuff so you see stuff that has not been closed and think it is on-topic.

Comment: Well, people are replying and discussing it at length in those other posts. I don´t commonly see others saying they are off-topic, which made me think mine is being targeted. Anyways, many times sudo is used in scripts, automation and even in small developments, which in my view, would make sudo questions aproppriate to be asked here. Sorry if I´m that mistaken.

Comment: Answered [at U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469059/117549)